# bypass http auth if acessed via index

Tags: php, http, authentication, nginx

i have the following set up for all my usenet programs using NGINX all locked behind SSL 443 port and http auth for each sub.

i use iDashboard so i can access them all via one page

https://github.com/causefx/iDashboard-PHP

I access the page on my idevices and i need to type in my username and password for each tab. is there away to only type it once if accessed directly from my domain yet still require it if accessed separately.

below is my nginx set up

```
 #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
   }

  server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name  mydomain.com, 192.168.0.21;



    ssl_certificate mykey.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key mykey.key;

    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_dhparam dhparam.pem;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;



        location /{
            root   html;
            index  index.php



        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;


        }




        location /web{
        if ($http_x_plex_device_name = '') { 
            rewrite ^/$ http://$http_host/web/index.php; 
        } 

        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.21:32400/web/index.html;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }

        location /nzbget {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.21:6789;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }

      location /plexpy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181/plexpy;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        auth_basic           "Plexpy closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        }   

    location /comics {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        auth_basic           "Comics closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        } 


        location /htpc {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        auth_basic           " HTPC closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        }

                location /nzbhydra {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5075;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    }
        location /sonarr {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8989;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        auth_basic           "TV closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

    }
    location /movies {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5050;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        auth_basic           "Movies closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;


            }
     location /deluge {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7741/;
        proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base "/deluge/";
        auth_basic           "Deluge closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

                    }
     location /plexrequest{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3579;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                        }
     location /myserver{
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.35:9090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                }
     location /calendar{
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.21:8989/sonarr/feed/calendar/NzbDrone.ics?apikey=myapi;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }



        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
            location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx-1.8.0/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

any help would be appericated

Comment: Use the same realm (string after auth_basic directive)

Comment: Sorry do you mean use the same auth_basic "close site"; on all?

Comment: Yes, the string after auth_basic is a realm. If you specify different realms your browser think it is different site. BTW, don't include verbs into realm - it should describe the whole your site